# Complex query in SQL. Leave only rows bigger than a treshold for each subset

Tags: sql

I have to make a complex query in SQL.
It's necessary to get only rows where employees have bigger salary than their bosses

The table structure is:

| name   | salary | employee_id | boss_id |

would appreciate any ideas

Comment: sample data and desired output are highly welcome

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: What is your question here? You haven't asked anything. Wgat about your attempts didn't work? What *were* those attempts?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.salary > (select tb.salary
                  from t tb
                  where tb.employee_id = t.boss_id
                 );
```

This is not a complex query.  It is actually pretty simple.

If `t` is really a complex query, you can use a CTE so it is only defined once:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
. . .;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new in SQL That's why question can sound not as clear as it should be